# Download ear from weblogic console

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic, weblogic12c

Is there any way by which I can download the ear from weblogic console ?

The ear is deployed to my server. I am using Weblogic 12c.

Comment: usually have to uncompress the EAR to deploy it. so mostly you can't find it compressed in the console. but you might find it in the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the EAR from the Console. You will need to get access to the host running your WLS instances (via SSH or FTP).
If  you uploaded your EAR through the console you will find it at [DOMAIN_HOME]/servers/AdminServer/upload. If your deployment staging mode is no stage or external stage (see Staging Mode Descriptions and Best Practices at http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/DEPGD/deploy.htm#DEPGD235= ) you can get the EAR location path in the App Overview Tab ( Select Deployments in the Domain Structure Tree and select your application on Summary on Deployments).